# How to improve predictions for consumer expenditure survey?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, random-forest, prediction, mse

I am trying to predict the total expenditure of a consumer from the consumer expenditure survey ([data here](https://www.bls.gov/cex/pumd_data.htm#csv)). I chose the variables as Age, Income, Urban/ Rural, Sex, Education to predict the total expenditures in an household.

The correlation between Income, Expenditure is relatively less, and the predictions have an RMSE of ~3000 for a data with mean ~10000. I used transformation, normalization, scaling, and cross validation for pre-processing the data. However, none of the models are performing well in predicting the total expenditure. Is there any way to improve the predictions?
( I tried Linear regression, Lasso, KNN, Random forest, Gradient boosting algorithms)

Here's the scatterplot for income and expenditure,
[scatterplot for income vs expenditure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAcbq.png)

I think the model is not performing well because of the less correlation. Any ideas to tackle such situations?

Comment: This looks a modelling issue rather than a programming one.

Comment: yes @greybeard you are right,  it doesn't look like a programming issue. If we are wrong, please try elaborating your question to get fast help.

Comment: Thanks @SunilLulla,@greybeard. As you said, I am facing issues in building the model. Any ideas for making predictions with the less correlated data?